# How to show the element that append with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a chat app like google hangout or snapchat with html, css and javascript. When I want to append a chat, I use

```
$(id_name).after(message)
```

I can append the message but what I want to know is that the message did not show on the screen without scrolling manually. How can I show the message that I append automatically? Please help me.

Following is the my code.

```
<div class="bubble" style="clear:both" id="talk_chat_from">
    <div id="talk_chat_detail"></div>
</div>
```

I append the message into the "talk_chat_detail".

Comment: Can you provide any code? What have you tried?

Comment: I think, you just need to scroll down tothe  bottom of the page, to show the newly appended message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scrollTop to scroll to the bottom of the page after you append the message

```
var $target = $('#talk_chat_detail'); 
$target.animate({scrollTop: $target.prop("scrollHeight") }, 300);
```

Comment: you can see a demo:https://plnkr.co/edit/HbPiAuOFK8804J19uy2e?p=preview

Comment: I modified my code to use your advice. I add "var $target = $(talk_chat_detail); $target.parent().animate({scrollTop: $target.prop("scrollHeight") }, 300);" But when I write the new message, new message didn't show width out scrolling manually.

Comment: can you provide a simplified jsfiddle/plunker/codepen?, this should work as you can see in my demo

Comment: I did it. Thank you for a nice advice.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `$target.animate` to `$target.animate({ scrollTop: $target.prop("scrollHeight") }, 1000);})`

here is the working fiddle : 
https://jsfiddle.net/Le1by7z0/

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#send').click(function() {
        var message = $("#message").val();//Here comes dynamic data binding
        var appendMessage = '#messageArea';//Message to append in div section
        $(appendMessage).append('<div style=height:10px;background:white;float:right>' + message + '</div> <br><hr>'); //user message dynamic div 
        var $target = $(appendMessage); // user dynamic div appended
          $target.animate({ scrollTop: $target.prop("scrollHeight") }, 1000);
    })
});
```

```css
#messageArea {
  width:320px;
  height:400px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="User Message" />
    <button type="button" id="send">append text message</button>
    <div id="messageArea">
        <div style="height:1000px;background-color:wheat"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i don't understand the last line in the click event,what syntax is that?

Comment: scrollTop: userMassage.prop("scrollHeight"); //showed on screen bottom of the page
are you talking about this one?

Comment: yes, i can't see the object associated with the scrollTop property

Comment: Ok I got it :-) Sorry:-)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use append and animate  in jquery. Here is the sample code ..

```
    <html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #test {
      width: 200px;
      height: 400px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }

    #test div {
      width: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <div class="bubble" style="clear:both" id="talk_chat_from">
    <div id="talk_chat_detail"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="write message" />
  <input type="button" id="sendMessage" value="Send" />

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#sendMessage").on('click', function() {
        var mes = $("#message").val();
        $("#talk_chat_detail").append(mes + "<br/>")
        $("#talk_chat_detail").animate({
          scrollTop: $target.prop("scrollHeight")
        }, 30);

      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use scrollTop, you just need to add following code right after the append call of your message and it will automatically scroll to the message,

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("div").offset().top
}, time);
```

div => Dom Element where you want to move scroll.

time => milliseconds, define the speed of the scroll.